# jQuery.html() will drop the select option's selected attribute

Tags: jquery, html

has a html generated dynamically, there is a select element on it.
We could chose an option inside it, and it works fine.

just like:

```
<div id="test">
  <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Then try to use:

```
var htmlstr= jQuery("#test").html();
alert(htmlstr);
```

to get the html string. In IE it's OK.
But in chrome(newest version), the option's selected attribute is dropped from the string.
the alert(htmlstr) returns result like this:

```
<div id="test">
   <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

The selected="selected" is missing.

I use jquery-1.9.1.min.js

I don't know it jquery's problem or chorme's problem.

thank you very much!
Or How I could get the html above in another way? I need to save it into database.

yours,
Ivan

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/V344S/) Working Fine in Chrome version  `34.0.1847.131 m` and also in `34.0.1847.137 m`

Comment: I get the html correctly in the chrome. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NuYN8/. No modifications made but it's working correctly

Comment: Which version of chrome used? For me it's working correctly in chrome Version 34.0.1847.131 m.  http://jsfiddle.net/XLULL/

Comment: This is working OK, why the upvotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem finally.
It's my misunderstood of the  element's behavior. I had thought that when I select a  element, it will mark the option I selected as "selected=seleted" automatically.
Not it's not.

I I changed the html as:

```
<select id='conditionpref"+connum+"' style='width:65px;'  onchange ='javascript:return changeconditionpref.apply(this);' name=''><option value='0'>0</option><option value='1'>1</option></select>
```

and set the js code as:

```
function changeconditionpref()
{
 var id=jQuery(this).attr("id");
  jQuery("#"+id+" option:selected").attr('selected','selected');
}
```

Now the problem is gone.

Thank you all!

yours,
Ivan

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine in latest Chrome in every single version of jQuery I tested. I would expect the alert to output just the select, without the parent div ... and that's what the following jsfiddle outputs:

```
$(function() {
    var div = $('<div id="test"/>'),
        opt = $('<option/>');
    $('<select/>').html( opt.clone().val(1).text(1) )
    .append( opt.clone().val(2).text(2).attr('selected','selected') )
    .appendTo( div.appendTo('body') );
    console.log( $('#test').html() );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/886Y3/

**output**:

```
<select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2" selected="selected">2</option></select>
```

**Note**: Please double check to make sure you don't have another element on the page with the same id="test". If there is, then the inconsistent browser results would be expected as there's no guarantee that different browsers will treat invalid HTML the same way.